# How to capture running log using bash script? [Case Closed]

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, solaris, logfile

I'm a new player in bash scripting. There's something that I want to know about capture logfile using bash script.

Let's say there is a server which store logfile every hour with format file below.

```
file[20160509_130000].log
```

The logfile has detailed information like this.

> ```
> 13:00:00 INFO  [file.chdev130] Event: ADIEVN_PLAY_DONE, Finished  , nbytes=16360
> 13:00:00 INFO  [file.chdev39] adiCollectDigits() success
> ```

My question is how can i read and store the running log or one hour before to get specific parameter (e.g. "Event") to new file using bash scripting?

Can someone teach me how to do it? Thanks.

**Update**
Here the flow that I want (for this time I want to know how the first point works):

1. Get the running log or one hour before.
2. Read the 15 minute interval (13:00:00 - 13:15:00).
3. grep the parameter (e.g. "Event) in that interval.
4. Count the parameter.
5. Store it to another file.

## SOLVED

Here the solution in case someone need it.

1. List all the content based on time stamp using `ls -t` then pipe it
2. Use `grep -v ^d` (i still doesn't know the exact explanation for ^d), pipe again
3. Display first few lines with `head`

So the result is,

> ```
> ls -t *.log | grep -v ^d | head -1 (for display the running log)
> ls -t *.log | grep -v ^d | head -2 | tail -1 (for display the one log before the running log)
> ```

Hope it'll help. Thanks

== Case Closed ==

Comment: You can get your `Event` line from each log simply with `grep 'Event' logfilename`. You can get the `Event` line from *all* logs in a directory with `grep 'Event' /path/to/log/file*`. You can watch the directory for a new log with `inotifywait`. Look at `man grep` and `man inotifywait`

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f /path-to-logfile` will allow you to read a file continuously until you cancel `tail` execution.
`grep "^13:" /path-to-logfile` will show you all strings in the file, which starts from "13:", in our case you'll get every record for 13-th hour.
`grep "Event" /path-to-logfile` will show you all strings with "Event" in them, i think, you got the idea about **grep** already. )

Comment: Not entirely sure what he is trying to get out of the log file or if it is supposed to trigger another action programmatically, but I think piping tail -f <logfile> | grep "pattern being waited for" is another valid option. That output could then be redirected to a file. Can you describe what flow you want in more detail?

Comment: The main purpose is i want to get the log every 15 minutes from running log or one hour before. So, 1) Get the running log or one hour before. 2) Read the 15 minute interval (13:00:00 - 13:15:00) 3) grep the parameter (e.g. "Event) in that interval. 4) Count the parameter. 5) Store it to another file. I know I can use grep to get the string "Event" but I still trying to use it in bash script.

Comment: I don't get it. What's stopping you from using grep inside of the script?

Comment: I'm using grep for get the "Event", what I want to know how can I get the running logfile? It's not efficient if I type the logfile name everytime i want to execute the script.

Comment: Upload your script somewhere and give me the link, let's get it through. )

Comment: Here the script --> https://jpst.it/IyDi it's not finished yet and still in progress. thanks for your help. i appreciate it.

Comment: By "count the parameter" what do you mean, exactly? You want to count how many times it appears in that period or you want to summarize the parameter values?

Comment: I want to count the parameter in the range of time. In my case, every 15 minute. Count the parameter in 15:00:00 - 15:15:00, 15:16:00 - 15:30:00, and so on

Comment: Let's say that we've got two strings with parameter values "4" and "5", what script should do with them? Count them and then result will be "2" or summarize them and result will be "9"?

Comment: Here the example. There is ADIEVN_PLAY_DONE and ADIEVN_PLAY_FAILED in logfile with parameter "Event". So I want to count how many DONE and FAILED in the logfile with parameter "Event". can you tell me how to read running logfile?

Comment: Sorry, forgot one important option of `tail` - in order to open file not from the end you have to specify row number by using `-n300` option, where 300 will be the 300th row from the end of the file - just put in `-n` option whatever value you need.

Comment: hmm, so i must know how many line which contain the parameter in the range 15 minutes. how about i use `ls *.log /directory_logfile | sort -r` so the most recent logfile is display in top? but i still dont know how to get the recent logfile. is it same logic with array so the recent logfile in the top is [0]?

Comment: What about modification date or filename of a logfile?

Comment: i already found it, but i dont know if its appropriate to use or not. Here the command: `now=ls -t *.log | grep -v ^d | head -1` (now is for recent logfile) and `prev=ls -t *.log | grep -v ^d | head -2 | tail -1` (prev is for one-hour before logfile)

Comment: That seems to me like something that's going to shoot you in the leg one day. Can you show me some examples of a log filenames and explain, why you can't use filename to determine is it current log or not?

Comment: Here the example of some logfile http://pastebin.com/CGqemX4m. Sorry, but what do you mean with use filename to determine is it current log or not? I'm not quite understand.

Comment: Let's say, there is two logs - file[20160519_010000.log] and file[20160519_020000.log], which one is going to be the current log? The one that has bigger value of the six digits between "20160519_" and ".log", right? Catching my drift? )

Comment: the current one is the one that has bigger value or has a same hours with today hours. For example, current hours is 06:15 so the current logfile is file[20160519_060000.log].

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the current or the previous log filename using `date`, using your logfile name convention:

```
fname="file[`date -v-1H '+%Y%m%d_%H0000'`].log"
```

will give you the previous filename. Omit `-v-1H` to get the current one.

For the 15-minute intervals, you may use regexps like `'^\d\d:(0\d|1[0-4])'` for 00:00-14:59 interval, `'^\d\d:(1[5-9]|2\d)'` for 15:00-29:59, etc.
For example, in the first regex, `^` matches the beginning of the line, `\d\d:` matches "two digits and a colon", and `(0\d|1[0-4])` matches either 0 with any adjacent digit, or 1 with adjacent digit from 0 to 4. In the second regex, `(1[5-9]|2\d)` matches 1 with digit from 5 to 9, or 2 with any digit.

Then you `grep -Po '(?<=Event: ).+(?=,)'` the type of events in your log, assuming that the type of event always ends with a `,`. That regexp will greedily match any symbols, as many as it can, starting from one symbol, if they are between strings `Event:` and `,` (`Event:` and `,` themselves are not matched, that's what lookbehind/lookaheads are for). Then use `sort | uniq -c` to count number of different events entries .

So the resulting script would look something like

```
fname="file[`date -v-1H '+%Y%m%d_%H0000'`].log"
grep -P '^\d\d:(0\d|1[0-4])' "$fname" | grep -Po '(?<=Event: ).+(?=,)' | sort | uniq -c > "/tmp/$fname_00-14"  # entries for first 15 minutes
grep -P '^\d\d:(1[5-9]|2\d)' "$fname" | grep -Po '(?<=Event: ).+(?=,)' | sort | uniq -c > "/tmp/$fname_15-29"  # entries for second 15 minutes
grep -P '^\d\d:(3\d|4[0-4])' "$fname" | grep -Po '(?<=Event: ).+(?=,)' | sort | uniq -c > "/tmp/$fname_30-44"  # entries for third 15 minutes
grep -P '^\d\d:(4[5-9]|5\d)' "$fname" | grep -Po '(?<=Event: ).+(?=,)' | sort | uniq -c > "/tmp/$fname_45-59"  # entries for fourth 15 minutes
```

for the last hour log.

Another approach is to use `logtail` with cron entries to get last log entries, instead of grepping. You can set up your script to be run by cron at 00, 15, 30 and 45 minutes each hour, determine the log filename inside it and logtail the file like `logtail -f "$fname"`. The catch here would be that when running at 00 minutes, you'd need to use the `-v-1H` switch for date, and this approach is not as accurate as grepping out the times.

Comment: can you explain to me the construct of regex command? it's my first time see that and for get the current and one-hour before logfile i already find it but i dont know if its appropriate to use or not. Here the command:

`nn=ls -t *.log | grep -v ^d | head -1` (nn is for recent logfile) and 
`pp=ls -t *.log | grep -v ^d | head -2 | tail -1` (pp is for one-hour before logfile)

Comment: As for your `nn=` and `pp=` commands, sure you can use them, assuming there are no other `.log` files in that directory but the logs of your application, and I don't understand why you do `grep -v ^d` there.
As for construct of regex commands, which needs an explanation? Do you need a piped example or you need an explanation about regexes themselves?

Comment: If it's not bother you, i need a short explanation about regexes or if it's too long you can insert the link where i can read. I still searching the simple explanation about regex. for my command, i found it as alias in a server. i dont know who make that alias. but the result is what i want.

Comment: I've added some explanations in the answer. If it's still unclear what those regexes do, I advise to browse through this [resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), it's really useful.

Comment: I can't run the script. it says, "grep: illegal option --P. Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . " Here the script that I'm trying http://pastebin.com/DrZJEury

Comment: I suspect that you use some version of BSD grep that doesn't support Perl regex flavor. I'd recommend to use GNU version, or you can do something like `egrep '^[0-9][0-9]:(0[0-9]|1[0-4])' "$fname" | egrep -o 'Event: .+,' | sed -e 's/Event: //g' -e 's/,$//g' | sort | uniq -c > "/opt/player/test/${fname}_00-14"`, with sed serving to clean the unneeded stuff from the string.

Comment: still can't run the script. now the problem is "egrep: illegal option -- o". I use SunOS 5.10 Sparc Sun-Fire-T200

Comment: Oh. Read your man for grep/egrep for 'print out only matching part of string' option or something like that. Never used SunOS to be honest.